# Выделить цветом часть предыдущего меню

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, как можно сделать меню как на скрине.
Как сделать изменение цвета при наведении на меню (что бы захватывало скругления предыдущего меню).
Спасибо

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Календарь событий</li>
        <li>Работа с клиентами</li>
        <li>Справочник</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гляньте в сторону табов, как они устроены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отрицательные маргины и немного `z-index`. Решение не особо универсальное, но вполне отвечает на вопрос в какую сторону вам копать.

```
 & + .navigation__item {
      margin-left: -30px;
 }

 &:nth-child(1) {
      z-index: 3;
 }

 &:nth-child(2) {
      z-index: 2;
 }

 &:nth-child(3) {
      z-index: 1;
 }
```

[Сodepen](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/MzbjaM)